# Multi Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help, I need to auto increment lines in a select, except that I have to restart my incrementation with each new value of the id .. I already try with (@cnt: = @cnt + 1 ) or COUNT (*) that counts the occurrence, but I never reach my desired result

I get each time

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ increment |   id  +  value +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1     |  1    |  foo   +
+     2     |  1    |  bar   +
+     3     |  2    |  foo   +
+     4     |  3    |  bar   +
+     5     |  3    |  foo   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

While I would like that

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ increment |   id  +  value +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1     |   1   |  foo   +
+     2     |   1   |  bar   +
+     1     |   2   |  foo   +
+     1     |   3   |  bar   +
+     2     |   3   |  foo   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Don't try to hack an auto increment column to do this.  What you want here is just row number applied with a partition on the `id` column.

Comment: There are tons of already answered questions here.

Comment: What I want is to be able to give a number starting with 1 for each ID at its different value.

And not just self-increment all my lines as I could see on the internet

Comment: Look into "simulating row number in MySQL."  Or, if you're using a very recent version of MySQL, use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Thx Tim, I found with what you told me

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that leverages an approach documented by https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/.   It utilizes variable and avoids any Lazy evaluation issues as "MySQL doesn't evaluate expressions containing user variables until they are sent to the client".  It use the approach of using a functions to force immediate evaluation of the variables.

Here is what I used on sqlfiddle.com to try out:

Table and creation and insert of values.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`Id` int, `value` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
(`Id`, `value`)
VALUES
(1, 'foo'),
(1, 'bar'),
(2, 'foo'),
(3, 'bar'),
(3, 'foo')
;
```

And the sql query for MySQL

```
set @increment := 0, @id := '';

select @increment,  id, value
from Table1
where 0 <= greatest(
@increment := if(@id = id, @increment + 1, 1),
least(0, @id := id));
```

Here is the result:

```
@increment  id  value
1   1   foo
2   1   bar
1   2   foo
1   3   bar
2   3   foo
```